# paneltest=a and result=b then give me results for (paneltest=a & paneltest=b & paneltest=c)

Tags: join, select, subquery, case, common-table-expression

OMG please be kind I have struggled with this complex problem for days and I am a complete newbie.

IF paneltest(133) is Reactive then all results for  tests paneltest(2154) and paneltest(2157) should be reported whether they are reactive or non reactive. If paneltest(133) is non reactive then neither paneltest(2154) or paneltest(2157) should be reported.

Basically if this one test has a result that is reactive then I need that result plus I need the test results for two other test also.  if its not reactive then I don't need any of them.

| panelTestKey | t.name 'test' | result | orgChartNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 133 | paneltest133 | Reactive | patient1 |
| 2154 | paneltest2154 | Reactive | patient1 |
| 2157 | paneltest2157 | NonReactive | patient1 |
| 2157 | paneltest133 | NonReactive | patient2 |
| 2157 | paneltest2157 | NonReactive | patient2 |
| 2157 | paneltest2157 | NonReactive | patient2 |

```
select distinct
pt.panelTestKey,
p.orgChartNumber,
t.name 'test',
r.result

FROM mytables rq

WHERE pt.paneltestKey IN (133)
AND pt.isnonreportable = 0
AND ((CONVERT(varchar(50), dbo.EpochToLocal(rq.finalDeliverystamp), 112)) >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0))    --shows testing done yesterday;can change day number to pull other date data
AND ((CONVERT(varchar(50), dbo.EpochToLocal(rq.finalDeliverystamp), 112)) < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0))   --shows testing not done today
and r.result='Reactive'
AND valuetoReport = 1
```

I have tried CTE but could not understand how this works.
I have tried to write as a subquery.
Tried a case statement.

I guess what I don't really understand is what I need to make this work.

Results I want is for patient1 to show up with results for all three of the tests patient2 should not show up because 133 is NonReactive.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH alltests AS (
```

SELECT DISTINCT
rq.requisitionkey,pt.panelTestKey,t.name 'test',r.result
FROM mytabables rq

WHERE
pt.paneltestKey IN (133,2154,2157)
AND pt.isnonreportable = 0
AND ((CONVERT(varchar(50), dbo.EpochToLocal(rq.finalDeliverystamp), 112)) >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0))    --shows testing done yesterday;can change day number to pull other date data
AND ((CONVERT(varchar(50), dbo.EpochToLocal(rq.finalDeliverystamp), 112)) < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0))   --shows testing not done today
AND valuetoReport = 1
)

SELECT alt.requisitionKey,alt.result,alt.panelTestKey,alt.test
FROM alltests alt

JOIN alltests
ON alltests.requisitionkey = alt.requisitionkey AND
(alltests.paneltestKey=133 and alltests.result='Reactive');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).